# Select group by with conditions

Tags: sql-server

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8otLv.jpg

I want to select names 
when sum( Productivity) >= 3000  and Date='2017-12-25'
group by Machines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with `SUM`, with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
  names,
  Machines
FROM Table1
where Date = '2017-12-25'
group by names, Machines 
HAVING sum(Productivity) >= 3000;
```

- [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8a67/5)

Comment: The OP desires 'sum( Productivity) >= 3000' not 'Productivity >= 3000'

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'when'.